# How to show all files from DB horizontaly using php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, crud

I have Uploaded files to a directory and in database and i want to show the files in the browser and make the downloadable but on one file is showing in the browser. [How it shows one file in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F9E93.png). Here is how the database looks like [Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTk1p.png). Here is the Directory of my Files [Image Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pX9cJ.png) And the code that i wrote

```
<?php
     $Year = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT distinct `Year` FROM `returndocs` WHERE EmailAddress='$name'");
     $Returns = 'Returns';
     if($Year->num_rows>0)
         {
            while ($row=$Year->fetch_assoc())
                {
                   echo "<button type='button' class='collapsible'>
                           <div style='display:flex'>
                              <div><img src='../Assets/images/icons/folder-icon.png' width='18' height='18'></div>
                                <div style='margin-left:5px;'>".$row['Year'].' '.$Returns."</div>
                           </div>
                         </button>";
                }
          }
     else{
             echo "<h6 style='color:#bf9038;'>No returns Submitted!</h6>";
         }
// Viewing files from Db and from directory 
$SelectUploadedFiles = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM `returndocs` where EmailAddress='$name';");
if($SelectUploadedFiles->num_rows > 0)
   {
       while($file=$SelectUploadedFiles->fetch_assoc())
            {
               echo "<div class='content'>
                      <table>
                          <tr><a href=".$file['ReturnDir']." download>".$file['ReturnName']."</a></tr>
                      </table>
                  </div>";
             }
    }
?>
```

How can i make the images horizontally styled i.e movies.txt followed by procurement.pdf etc. like this [Procument file should be under movies.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gy1ms.png).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your table outside of the loop and inside the loop only the rows.

Example:

```php
if($SelectUploadedFiles->num_rows > 0) {
    // Define the div and table opening elements
    $ouput = '<div class="content"><table>';
    while($file=$SelectUploadedFiles->fetch_assoc()) {
        // Append for each entry a new table row
        $output .= '<tr><td><a href="' . $file['ReturnDir'] . '"> ' . $file['ReturnName'] . '</a></td></tr>';
    }
    // Close the table and div elements
    $output .= '</table></div>';
    // Show the table
    echo $output;
}
```

Btw. Your code is vulnerable for SQL injections!

Comment: To show the files in one row (e.g. file1.txt, file2.txt ...) just move the `<tr><td></td></tr>` out of the loop and only append the links inside the loop.

`$output .= '<a href="' . $file['ReturnDir'] . '"> ' . $file['ReturnName'] . '</a> ';`

Answer (score 1):

I saw you got the answer for this but I would like to add some **additional information** to that;

It is always advisable to **avoid tables in HTML** these days as they have got many problems, which could be easily handled by other HTML tags like ul, li etc.

*For more details* : https://www.lifewire.com/dont-use-tables-for-layout-3468941

If you look at most modern websites its **div** and **ul** that is used the most as they have less code, flexible and easy to manage. Again, HTML is just to put your data in place.

Here you want to display them horizontally, which should be a task assigned to **CSS**. It's so simple, all you have to do is use flex and mention the way you want and it does that for you in the most simple and faster way.

```css
    ul li{
    display:block;
    text-decoration:none;
    }

    ul{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    }
    
    .reverse {
    flex-direction:column-reverse;
    }
```

```html
    <h4>Listing Horizontally</h4>
    <ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
 </ul>
    <h4 >Listing Horizontally in Reverse</h4>
    <ul class="reverse">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
 </ul>
```

That's it..Always use the backend to fetch data and display that's it period. **How to display is CSS**

Hope this makes sense for you ...

Comment: While were at it, mixing html with php is way worse of a sin. We have had tempting libraries for at least a decade, where are people still learning this.

Comment: I totally understand how deadly is it to mix php and html. I took a while to understand this. Just get the data using php , put that to necessary html tag and then only use CSS to fix the layout. Else in large scale this can cause performance issues. THe best part is that the CSS gets cached so your site loads faster .